# How can I use GLKView to draw at a lower resolution?

Tags: ios, opengl-es-2.0, glkview

I have an app based on "OpenGL Game" Xcode template, for everyday testing/dev I would like to render full screen but at lower resolution in simulator (e.g. 1/2 or 1/4). Any efficient/savvy way to put this in place?

(in case anybody wonder, I want to do this because my app is running very slow in simulator, so rendering at a smaller resolution would make testing/debugging a lot more programmer-friendly)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `contentScaleFactor` of the view is 2.0 by default on a Retina display. If you reduce the scale factor, `GLKView` automatically uses a smaller framebuffer and scales its contents up to screen size for display.

Scale factor 1.0 is half size (or the same number of pixels as a non-Retina screen). 0.5 would be quarter size — big, chunky pixels on any display. Non-integral scale factors between 1.0 and 2.0 work, too, and can be a great way to compromise between quality and performance on a Retina display.

---

Update: just had a vote remind me of this answer. I'm surprised I wouldn't have said this originally, but I may as well add it now...

The iOS Simulator runs OpenGL ES using a software renderer (i.e. on the host Mac's CPU, not its GPU). That's why it's slow. Performance characteristics *and rendering results* can vary from renderer to renderer, so never trust the simulator for anything OpenGL/GPU-related (except perhaps in very broad strokes).

Comment: Changing the content scale factor confuses my rendering engine, but works - thanks!